# How should I use line number and column number to get element in XML in JAVA

Tags: java, xml, validation, xsd, jaxb

Hi I am using JAXB and Marshal/Unmarshal Schema Validation. I have a XML file and XSD schema for validation. Code are like this:

Validation.java

```
try{
    SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    Schema schema = sf.newSchema(new File("./src/main/resources/validation.xsd"));
    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(AddCustomer.class);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
    unmarshaller.setSchema(schema);
    unmarshaller.setEventHandler(new MyValidationEventHandler());
    AddCustomer addCustomer_Validation= (AddCustomer) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("./src/main/resources/AddCustomer.xml"));
    logger.info("AddCustomer passed validation.");
} catch(UnmarshalException ex) {
    logger.info("linked ex: " + ex.getLinkedException().toString());
    String str = ex.getLinkedException().toString();
    int lineNumberIndex = str.indexOf("lineNumber:");
    int lineNumber = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(lineNumberIndex+12,lineNumberIndex+13));
    logger.info("lineNumber:" +lineNumber);
    int columnIndex = str.indexOf("columnNumber:");
    int columNumber = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(columnIndex+14,columnIndex+16));
    logger.info("columnNumber: " + columNumber);
}
```

Some of the XML file is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<AddCustomer xmlns="http://...">
<Customer>
    <DirectoryInformation>
        <PortalID>32        4   5</PortalID>
        <AccountID>2732</AccountID>
```

From the code above, I could get validate the XML is valid against the XSD. The logger file is something like this:

```
INFO [main] Validation- linked ex: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:.../src/main/resources/AddCustomer.xml; lineNumber: 5; columnNumber: 41; cvc-pattern-valid: Value '32       4   5' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern '[ !-~]*' for type 'an..35'.
INFO [main] Validation- lineNumber: 5
INFO [main] Validation- columnNumber: 41
```

The validation is correct and in the xml file, the value of PortalID is not valid against the XSD schema, and the log file can tell me the location is "lineNumber 5 and ColumNumber 41" which is exactly the place for PortalID.

But what I want is to use this **lineNumber 5 and ColumNumber 41** to printout that the element **PortalID** in the XML is not valid. Is there any way to do that? 
Thank you so much!

Comment: Could you please clarify what you want to do? BTW: I hope you realise that there are getters on `SAXParseException` for the line and column number, so there is no need to do that string parsing to get them.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Hi Thank you for your answer. I want to use the line number and the column number to locate the element which is not valid. In my case, the value of the element "PortalID" is not valid so that I want to print out that the element "PortalID" is not valid. So any idea what to do that?

Comment: I don't use a lot of XML parsing, but wouldn't you be better of using your [`ValidationEventHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/ValidationEventHandler.html)? Events posted on that contain a [`ValidationEventLocator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/ValidationEventLocator.html) that contains the information you want (AFAIK, it has been a while since I have done anything with that).

Comment: Hi Mark, I could use ValidationEventLocator, however, the event.getLocator().getObject return me null, and the event.getLocator().getLineNumber(), event.getLocator().getColumnNumber() return me the same number as I mentioned above. However, what I want is to return something to indicate that the **PortalID** is not valid. Where can I get this one? Thanks!

Comment: Does `getLocator().getNode()` return anything?

Comment: Hi Mark, I tried this     getLocator().getNode(), but return null still.

Comment: Ok, then my guessing game is at an end, hopefully someone else drops by who regularly does and have an idea, but otherwise you are probably going to have to re-read the file and take sufficient context, or run it through a SAX parser yourself and remember the context before the error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130968/discussion-between-sherryhw-and-mark-rotteveel).

Answer (score 0):

To get the name of the last element parsed you could put a custom ContentHandler that records the last element between the SAXParser and the JAXB handler.

To do that you must use a [SAXSource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/sax/SAXSource.html) and create a custom [XMLFilter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/xml/sax/XMLFilter.html) implementation extending [XMLFilterImpl](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/xml/sax/helpers/XMLFilterImpl.html)

1. pass a `SAXSource` to the `Unmarshaller` instead than a `File` and in the `SAXSource` configure an `XMLReader`. This is explained in [Unmarshalling from a javax.xml.transform.sax.SAXSource using a client specified validating SAX2.0 parser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html)
2. Do not configure the `SAXSource` with the "real" `XMLReader` implementation as in Javadoc linked code but use the custom XMLFilter that wraps the "real" `XMLReader`.

   ```
      XMLReader xmlReader = saxParser.getXMLReader();
      RecordingXMLFilter xmlFilter = new RecordingXMLFilter(xmlReader);
      SAXSource source =
      new SAXSource(xmlFilter, new InputSource(new FileInputStream(new File("./src/main/resources/AddCustomer.xml")));
   ```
3. The custom filter `RecordingXMLFilter` could be:

   ```
   private static final class RecordingXMLFilter extends XMLFilterImpl
   {

   String lastElement;

   private RecordingXMLFilter(XMLReader parent)
   {
       super(parent);
   }

   @Override
   public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException
   {
       lastElement = qName;
       super.startElement(uri, localName, qName, attributes);
   }
   }
   ```
4. In exception handling code use `xmlFilter.lastElement` to get the QName of the last element parsed.

BTW To get line numbers do in this way, messages could be different in different locales or change between versions.

```
    try
    {
        ..........
    }
    catch(UnmarshalException ex) {
        Throwable linked = ex.getLinkedException();
        if (linked instanceof SAXParseException)
        {
            SAXParseException t = (SAXParseException) linked;
            int lineNumber = t.getLineNumber();
            int columNumber = t.getColumnNumber();
            logger.info("lineNumber:" +lineNumber);
            logger.info("columnNumber: " + columNumber);

        }
    }
```